# How do you pass variable to ASP.NET Core's Tag Helpers attributes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I need to dynamically generate the route name for my form and pass it to the `form` tag helper. This is what I have:

```
@{ string route = GetRouteName(); // returns "MyRouteName" }

<form asp-route="route"></form>
<p>@route</p>
```

This results in the following markup (note there is no value for action):

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
</form>
<p>MyRouteName</p>
```

I know that the route name is being generated correctly because it is being put in the `p` tag, and if I just type it into the `asp-route` attribute directly it works as expected.

I have tried the following variations with no difference in result:

```
<form asp-route="GetRouteName()"></form>
<form asp-route="@GetRouteName()"></form>
<form asp-route="@route"></form>
```

Is there a way to pass a variable to the `asp-route` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `<form asp-route="GetRouteName()"></form>` won't work as this passes the "GetRouteName()" string instead of the result of the method call.

However, `<form asp-route="@GetRouteName()"></form>` or `<form asp-route="@route"></form>` does definitely work. I've put together a sample to prove this:

1. Create an empty ASP.NET Core MVC app:

   ```
   dotnet new mvc
   ```
2. Add a controller for testing (*Controllers/TestController.cs*):

   ```
   public class TestController : Controller
   {
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           if (HttpMethods.IsGet(Request.Method))
               return View();
           else
               return Content($"{Request.Method} {UriHelper.BuildRelative(Request.PathBase, Request.Path, Request.QueryString)}");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the related view (*Views/Test/Index.cshtml*):

   ```
   @functions { string GetRouteName() => "MyRouteName"; }

   @{ string route = GetRouteName(); /* returns "MyRouteName" */ }

   <p>Route name: @route</p>

   <p>Route: @Url.RouteUrl(route)</p>

   <form asp-route="@route">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ```
4. Define a route named *MyRouteName* in the *Startup.Configure* method:

   ```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "MyRouteName",
           template: "Test/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Test" });

       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "AnotherRouteName",
           template: "",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
   });
   ```
5. Start the app, navigate to `/Test/Index` and verify that the *action* attribute of the generated HTML form is correct. (Tested on ASP.NET Core 2.0 and 2.1.)

It's very likely that the problem lies in your route configuration: an empty *action* attribute is generated when you pass an undefined route name in the *asp-route* attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response, not in a position to try anything right now, but it worked when I copy/pasted the route name that was in the `<p>` tags it worked just fine. I wish it would throw an error rather than just fall back to no value!

Comment: You were 100% correct Adam, I was being dumb! My route names contain slashes and the one being generated had a preceding slash that shouldn't have been there.